# Permission error when puppet-agent requesting ssl certificate on fedora 23

Tags: puppet, fedora

I recently set up puppet server/agent instances on separate vm both running fedora 23 workstation. When requesting a certificate from agent I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 400 on SERVER: Cannot save fedoraclient.localdomain; parent directory /etc/puppet/ssl/ca/requests is not writable
```

Previously I was not able to connect to server at all, then I found the command: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8140/tcp --permanent` which let's me connect, unfortunately now I'm getting the error mentioned above. I can ping from client to server and vice versa, so I'm guessing it has something to do with selinux maybe.

Also, I can see that on agent `/etc/puppet` doesn't have `ssl` directory, it's in the location: `/var/lib/puppet`. Doing a `ls -l` there results in

```
drwxr-x---. 2 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 clientbucket
drwxr-x---. 2 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 client_data
drwxr-x---. 2 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 client_yaml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 facts.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 lib
drwxr-x---. 2 puppet puppet 4096 Feb  4 21:11 preview
drwxrwx--x. 7 puppet puppet 4096 Feb  4 21:11 ssl
drwxr-xr-t. 3 root   root   4096 Feb  4 21:11 state
```

Note: I'm running as root on both machines. I've found a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1235122). Unfortunately setting `setenforce` to 0 or modifying `/etc/selinux/config` doesn't solve the problem. I was wondering is there any workaround for this?

Comment: ok, my bad, I previously did a `setenforce 0` on agent. I disabled selinux on server and now it's working.

Comment: Don't forget to do [`setenforce 1`](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/) afterwards